# RSpec - How to add default content-type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

For my project, I need to add the header `HTTP_ACCEPT` to all my requests.

Is there a solution to avoid this on all my controllers' specs ?

```
before do
    @request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do |example|
    if example.metadata[:type] == :controller
      controller.request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = 'application/json'
    end
  end
end
```